# File is arriving empty when I attempt to transfer between computers using sockets

Tags: java, swing, sockets

Hi I relatively new to Java and very new to the networking side of it and I really need some help please..?

I have done some research the past few days as I did not know much if anything about networking a few days ago. There are similar questions that have been asked but I cant seem to get an answer to help me. Again I am very new to java networking and so do not know exactly how to go about this problem. Please Help...

I am working on a project with client/server relationship and I want the client to be able to transfer their personal music files over the socket. Every time I attempt to do it the file is created but it is empty. Could someone with networking experience help me please?

Server code:

```
 public class Server extends JFrame {


        //===============================
        // FIELDS
        //===============================

        // connection essentials
        private ServerSocket server;
        private Socket connection;
        private OutputStream outStream;
        private InputStream inStream;

        // file transfer essentials
        private FileInputStream fileInStream;
        private FileOutputStream fileOutStream;
        private BufferedInputStream bufInStream;
        private BufferedOutputStream bufOutStream;
        private int bytesRead;
        private int currentTot;

        // frame components
        private JTextArea textArea;
        private JButton ok;

        //===============================
        // CONSTRUCTORS
        //===============================

        public Server(){

            initComponents();

            try {
                runServer();
                getStreams();
                receiveFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.print( "Error in constructor - Server" );
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } // catch()
            finally{

                try {
                    close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println( "Error in finally - attempt to close" );
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } // catch()
            } // finally

        } // 0 Args  


        //===============================
        // CLASS METHODS
        //===============================

        private void runServer() throws IOException {

            *server = new ServerSocket( 7133, 100 );
            connection = server.accept(); // accept clients conn attempt
            textArea.setText( "Connection Established..." );
            //connection.setTcpNoDelay( true ); // stops nagles algorithm by 
            // halting buffering (waiting to receive confirmaion from client)

        } // runServer()

        private void getStreams() throws IOException{

            outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outStream.flush();

            inStream = connection.getInputStream();
            textArea.append( "\n\nReceiving files..." );

        } // getStreams()

        private void close() throws IOException{

            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();
            server.close();

        } // close()

        private void receiveFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

            byte byteArray[] = new byte[ 10000000 ];
            File receviedFile =  new File( "YES.mp3" );
            FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream( receviedFile );
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream BOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                bytesRead = inStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                currentTot = bytesRead;

                byteArray = BOS.toByteArray();

                do {
                    bytesRead = inStream.read(
                            byteArray, 0, (byteArray.length - currentTot));

                    if (bytesRead >= 0)
                        currentTot += bytesRead;

                    if(currentTot == byteArray.length )
                        textArea.append( "\n\nFile recieved" );



                } while (bytesRead > -1);

                BOS.write(byteArray, 0, currentTot);
                BOS.flush();
            }
            close();

        } // receiveFiles()

        private void initComponents() {

            // textArea
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            this.add( textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER );

            // send
            ok = new JButton( "OK" );
            this.add( ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

            addListeners();

            // frame fundamentals
            this.setVisible( true );
            this.setSize( 300, 150 );
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        } // initComponents()

        private void addListeners() {

            ok.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        textArea.setText( "File received and accepted" );

                    } // actionPerformed()
                }); // addActionListeners()

        } // addListeners()
        //===============================
        // SETTERS AND GETTERS
        //===============================

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Server server = new Server();
        }

    } // class{}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client extends JFrame {


    //===============================
    // FIELDS
    //===============================

    // connection essentials
    private Socket connection;
    private InputStream inStream;
    private OutputStream outStream;

    // file transfer essentials
    private FileInputStream fileInStream;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutStream;
    private BufferedInputStream bufInStream;
    private BufferedOutputStream bufOutStream;

    // frame components
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton choose;
    private JButton send;

    // file
    private File fileToSend;


    //===============================
    // CONSTRUCTORS
    //===============================

    public Client(){

        initComponents();

        try {
            getConnected();
            getStreams();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println( "Error in Client constructor" );
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally{

        } // finally

    }    
    //===============================
    // CLASS METHODS
    //===============================

    private void getConnected() throws IOException {

        connection = new Socket( InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 7133 );
        textArea.setText( "Connection Established..." );

    } // getConnected()

    private void getStreams() throws IOException {

        outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outStream.flush();

        inStream = connection.getInputStream();

    } // getStreams()

    private void close() throws IOException{

        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();
        connection.close();

    } // close()

    private void sendFile( final File transfer ) 
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        byte fileInBytes[] = new byte[ (int) transfer.length() ];
        fileInStream = new FileInputStream( transfer );
        int start = 0;

        textArea.setText( "Sending files...." );
        while( (start = inStream.read()) > 0 )
            outStream.write( fileInBytes, 0, fileInBytes.length );

        bufInStream = new BufferedInputStream( fileInStream );

        outStream.flush();

        textArea.setText( "Transfer complete" );
        close();

    } // sendFile()

    private void initComponents() {

        // choose
        choose = new JButton( "CHOOSE" );
        this.add( choose, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        // textArea
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        this.add( textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        // send
        send = new JButton( "SEND" );
        this.add( send, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        addListeners();

        // frame fundamentals
        this.setVisible( true );
        this.setSize( 300, 150 );
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    } // initComponents()

    private void addListeners() {

        choose.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    getFile();

                } // actionPerformed()
            }); // addActionListeners()

        send.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {
                                sendFile(fileToSend);

                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println(
                                        "Error in send - actionPerformed");
                                Logger.getLogger(
                                        Client.class.getName()).log(
                                                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                            } // catch ()
                        } // run()
                    }; // runnable()

                } // actionPerformed()           
            }); // addActionListeners()

    } // addListeners()

   private void getFile()
   {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(
         JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES );

      int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( this );

      // if user clicked Cancel button on dialog, return
      if ( result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION )
         System.exit( 1 );

      // getSelectedFile
      fileToSend = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

      // display error if invalid
      if ( ( fileToSend == null ) || ( fileToSend.getName().equals( "" ) ) )
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Invalid Name",
            "Invalid Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
         System.exit( 1 );
      } // end if

   } // end method getFile


    //===============================
    // SETTERS AND GETTERS
    //===============================

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = new Client();
    }

} // class{}
```

Comment: You're making a number of thread violations on the Swing API. Take a look at [Conurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details

Comment: Ok man thanks for the info.. I will have a look and sort my code.. cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your receiveFile() method, you read the first 10 MB of what's received - probably all of it - into `byteArray`.  Then, in the following line:

```
byteArray = BOS.toByteArray();
```

You throw away the previous value of `byteArray` including all the data you've received, replacing it with the empty contents of `BOS`.

What you need to do instead is read from the input stream into the buffer, then write from the buffer to your FileOutputStream.  There's no need to bother with a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply I really appreciate it. It makes a lot of sense what you are telling me, I am going to go and try and implement it in code now, it may take awhile as I am not too confident on the process but I will post my results when I get success..